# why does keras.applications inception not recognise my elephant?

Tags: keras

I have just started trying the keras applications. The example for resnet50 works fine. However the inception_v3 model thinks my elephant is a sports car. Where am I going wrong?

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(299, 299))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

preds = model.predict(x)
# decode the results into a list of tuples (class, description, probability)
# (one such list for each sample in the batch)
print('\nPredicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=10)[0])
```

Predicted: [('n04285008', 'sports_car', 0.58716565), ('n04041544', 'radio', 0.19915217), ('n03535780', 'horizontal_bar', 0.11363289), ('n03691459', 'loudspeaker', 0.059153806), ('n01669191', 'box_turtle', 0.012588425), ('n04286575', 'spotlight', 0.0068869498), ('n03594945', 'jeep', 0.005987139), ('n01728920', 'ringneck_snake', 0.0050685192), ('n03637318', 'lampshade', 0.0020551293), ('n03000134', 'chainlink_fence', 0.00168875)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot. Cut and pasted the imports including the preprocessing and decode predictions from the resnet50 example. Need to import these from inception_v3.

Comment: If it's any help: The title of your question made me chuckle.. Also you should check your sports car, there may be a snake in there.